# How to find out if new versions of npm-packages exists

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, bower, npm-install

I have a `package.json` that contains the following settings for the dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "3.1.1",
  "electron": "1.3.1"
}
```

I know there are newer versions for boostrap and electron.

I was asking myself: *Is there a way to find out if newer versions of the dependencies exists?*

In Bower.io I would sipmly run `bower list` which lists installed packages and possible updates and then run `bower update -S` to install the updates.

Is there similar workflow in `npm`?

A way that directly installs newer versions is

```
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "^3.1.1",
  "electron": "^1.3.1"
}
```

and running `npm up`. But there seems to be no command that only lists possible updates for the packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check with this command

> npm outdated

To check it globally 
Run the following command

> npm outdated -g --depth=0

Check more info [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated)

After checking  update all outdated package

> npm update

Answer (score 1):

Get the list of availables npm packages updates :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

Update the packages :

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update